# Spatial join in geopandas when overlapping polygons?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two datasets, one with points (shops) and one with polygons (districts).

The districts dataset sometimes has overlapping polygons (as I have buffered them).

I want to know if each polygon has any matching points?

```
joined = geopandas.sjoin(districts,shops, op='contains', how='inner')
joined
```

The above code probably give me only one of the matching polygons. How do I check each polygon?

Comment: This will normally give you all matching polygons / points pairs. I would suggest to try a small example, and show it here if it does not what you want.

Comment: *The above code probably* -- what do you mean by "probably"? did you try it? what happened?

Comment: You may want to change your parameters to how='right'

Answer (score 3):

## TL/DR

```py
gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="left", op="contains") \
.reset_index()\
.rename(columns={"index": "districts"})\
.groupby(["districts"])\
.agg(nshops=("index_right", "nunique"), lshops=("index_right", "unique"))\
.astype(str)\
.replace("[nan]", "")
```

## Explanations

### Problem setup

Let's said that we have 3 districts (**d1**, **d2** and **d3**). Two district overlap (**d1** and **d2**). We have 4 shops. **s1** is inside district **d1**, **s2** is inside district **d2**. **s12** inside district **d1** and **d2**. **s3** is not in any district.

We generate this geometry in python using `shapely`:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Create Polygons for the districts
d1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3), (0, 3)])
d2 = Polygon([(1, 1), (4, 1), (4, 4), (1, 4)])
d3 = Polygon([(5, 2), (6, 2), (6, 3), (5, 3)])
# Create Points for the shops
s1 = Point(0.5, 0.5)
s2 = Point(3.5, 3.5)
s3 = Point(4.5, 2)
# This shop is in distric 1 and distric 2.
s12 = Point(2, 2)
```

Saving the geometry into GeoPandas DataFrame and using matplotlib we can have a look at the configuration:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
districts = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], geometry=[d1, d2, d3])
shops = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=['s1', 's12', 's2', 's3'], geometry=[s1, s12, s2, s3])
ax = districts.boundary.plot()
shops.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now let's have a look at how spatial join are working in GeoPandas. We have to be careful at the order of the dataframe because the operation is not commutative. Meaning `gpd.sjoin(shops, districts, how="inner", op="contains")` is not equal to `gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="inner", op="contains")`.

### Now let's have a look to six arrangement:

#### 1 `gpd.sjoin(shops, districts, how="left", op="contains")`

|  | geometry | index_right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | POINT (0.5 0.5) | nan |
| s12 | POINT (2 2) | nan |
| s2 | POINT (3.5 3.5) | nan |
| s3 | POINT (4.5 2) | nan |

Keep the shops as index and filling districts columns with NaN.

#### 2 `gpd.sjoin(shops, districts, how="right", op="contains")`

|  | index_left | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | nan | `POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))` |
| d2 | nan | `POLYGON ((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))` |
| d3 | nan | `POLYGON ((5 2, 6 2, 6 3, 5 3, 5 2))` |

Keep the districts as index and filling shops columns with NaN.

#### 3 `gpd.sjoin(shops, districts, how="inner", op="contains")`

| geometry | index_right |
| --- | --- |

This return an empty dataframe because points can't contains polygons.

#### 4 `gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="left", op="contains")`

|  | geometry | index_right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | `POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))` | s1 |
| d1 | `POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))` | s12 |
| d2 | `POLYGON ((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))` | s12 |
| d2 | `POLYGON ((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))` | s2 |
| d3 | `POLYGON ((5 2, 6 2, 6 3, 5 3, 5 2))` | nan |

Keep the districts as index.

#### 5 `gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="right", op="contains")`

|  | index_left | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | d1 | POINT (0.5 0.5) |
| s12 | d1 | POINT (2 2) |
| s12 | d2 | POINT (2 2) |
| s2 | d2 | POINT (3.5 3.5) |
| s3 | nan | POINT (4.5 2) |

Keep shop as index .

#### 6 `gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="inner", op="contains")`

|  | geometry | index_right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | `POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))` | s1 |
| d1 | `POLYGON ((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0))` | s12 |
| d2 | `POLYGON ((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))` | s12 |
| d2 | `POLYGON ((1 1, 4 1, 4 4, 1 4, 1 1))` | s2 |

Close to what we obtain with left, keep districts as index, but drop NaN.

### Answer to the question

```py
    gpd.sjoin(districts, shops, how="left", op="contains") \
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={"index": "districts"})\
    .groupby(["districts"])\
    .agg(nshops=("index_right", "nunique"), lshops=("index_right", "unique"))\
    .astype(str)\
    .replace("[nan]", "")
```

| districts | nshops | lshops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d1 | 2 | ['s1' 's12'] |
| d2 | 2 | ['s12' 's2'] |
| d3 | 0 |  |

**Like this we can known if each polygon has any matching points**